# Servers window in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-wtp

I need to create an ODE server inside my Eclipse workspace, in the tutorial I'm following, it says to use the Server view under **Window->Show View->Other->Server->Servers**. However, I cannot find this option under 'Window->Show View->Other->Server->Servers', any ideas how to get it? I am using Eclipse 3.4.2 Ganymede (classic).

Comment: You can't find the Servers view list, or you can't find the server in that view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the Servers window is part of WTP (the Web Tools Platform) .  You can get that via the update center, though it may be easier to download [Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers](http://eclipse.org/home/categories/index.php?category=enterprise), which includes all the various bits and pieces that need to get cobbled together.

Comment: You may want to use this link to get the bits... since it leads you to the Eclipse IDE 3.4.2 for Java EE Developers: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/ganymede/SR2/eclipse-jee-ganymede-SR2-win32.zip